# How do I create an instance of the iPhone/iPad library PTShowcaseViewController in my own Project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I found this iOS demo project that incorporates many different libraries and frameworks. I would love to know how to create a new project and add all the necessary libraries and frameworks included in the PTShowcase demo project to my own project.

See:
https://github.com/exalted/PTShowcaseViewController

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the project you've mentioned above. I believe, it is more appropriate to ask via github.com issues instead. Cheers,